# Probabilities matrices and cellular automata in IDRISI

Tags: raster, change-detection, land-use, terrset, cellular-automata

I apologize for asking about such elementary things, but I am utterly new to IDRISI yet am now having to learn how to perform certain tasks with it on very short notice.

Am I right that, when Markov chain analysis is performed in IDRISI, one of the outputs is a probabilities matrix? In other words, for a certain location L, for which land-cover data for years A and B are available, one can generate a matrix of possible changes for each land use from year A to year B? Is it possible, then, to use this matrix as an input to a cellular automaton that would predict land-cover changes in another location, M, based on (for example) current land-use data there? What tool or tools in IDRISI are needed for this type of analysis?